# Is it valid to use different scaling techniques for different features in a dataset?

Tags: classification, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

I am currently working with a dataset that has a few different features. Ultimately, I would like to train a binary classification model on this dataset. I would like to scale my data, as I plan on trying a few different models - some of which require scaling and some that don't.

I plotted the distributions of each of my features and noticed that some seemed normally distributed while others seemed skewed. Others had big outliers, which impacted scaling negatively. I was wondering if it was possible to use different scaling techniques for the different features based on the scaling technique that works well with that distribution, e.g., using a standard scaler for scaling the normally distributed features, a minmax scaler for scaling the skewed features, and using a robust scaler for scaling the other features with significant outliers.

This seems logical to me on the surface, but I hadn't come across an example that used this, so I thought I would ask the internet to make sure I didn't miss something important. Most of the examples that I see use a single scaler for the entire dataset, but I'm thinking as long as I am consistent in my use of scaling methods, I should be fine?

The scaling techniques I am discussing are further outlined here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py